# errors when installing nodebb dependencies

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm trying to install nodebb from [these instructions](https://docs.nodebb.org/en/latest/installing/os/ubuntu.html), but I get a series of errors when I run `npm install`

```
npm install
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/passport-local/-/passport-local-1.0.0.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/nodebb-widget-essentials/-/nodebb-widget-essentials-0.1.0-5.tgz
npm ERR! fetch failed https://registry.npmjs.org/nodebb-theme-lavender/-/nodebb-theme-lavender-0.0.77.tgz
npm WARN engine hawk@0.10.2: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"0.10.30","npm":"1.4.21"})
npm WARN engine sntp@0.1.4: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"0.10.30","npm":"1.4.21"})
npm WARN engine cryptiles@0.1.3: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"0.10.30","npm":"1.4.21"})
npm WARN engine hoek@0.7.6: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"0.10.30","npm":"1.4.21"})
npm WARN engine boom@0.3.8: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"0.10.30","npm":"1.4.21"})

> hiredis@0.1.17 install /home/andy/dev/nodebb/node_modules/reds/node_modules/redis/node_modules/hiredis
> node-gyp rebuild

make: Entering directory `/home/andy/dev/nodebb/node_modules/reds/node_modules/redis/node_modules/hiredis/build'
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/hiredis/deps/hiredis/hiredis.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/hiredis/deps/hiredis/net.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/hiredis/deps/hiredis/sds.o
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/hiredis/deps/hiredis/async.o
  AR(target) Release/obj.target/deps/hiredis.a
  COPY Release/hiredis.a
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/hiredis/src/hiredis.o
make: g++: Command not found
make: *** [Release/obj.target/hiredis/src/hiredis.o] Error 127
make: Leaving directory `/home/andy/dev/nodebb/node_modules/reds/node_modules/redis/node_modules/hiredis/build'
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:267:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-33-generic
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/andy/dev/nodebb/node_modules/reds/node_modules/redis/node_modules/hiredis
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.30
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.13.1
gyp ERR! not ok
```

Is this something to do with my node version?

Comment: You need to install g++

Answer (score 0):

Your node/npm seems fine,
it has to do with a dependency that bulids some native code for nodejs, using npm-gyp.

@stropitek is right, its breaking because you don't have gcc installed (of which g++ is part of)

if you're running Ubuntu, this should work...

`sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential`

Which will update you're sources and install build tools, which should make node-gyp happy and you'll be able to `npm install` happily!

Comment: On OSX, you'll need to install XCode, and on Windows Visual studio I guess

Comment: Quite right, and python when in Windows...bit.ly/VpDges